# How to reshape this data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, transpose

**Input df:**

```
user attr val       date
100    a  10      2012-11-09
100    b  20      2012-11-08
101    a  11      2012-11-09
```

**Output df:**

```
user attr_a val_a date_a     attr_b  val_b date_b
100    a  10      2012-11-09    b     20      2012-11-08 
101    a  11      2012-11-09
```

Need help in R to reshape the input data frame into the desired output data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a brief function that splices your data frame
based on a given column (byCol) having a specified value (byVal)

```
spliceDF <- function(df, byVal, byCol="attr", preserveField="user")  {
# returns spliced df with renamed columns

  # identify which rows will be returned
  rows <- df[byCol]==byVal

  # append the suffix
  nm <- names(df)!=preserveField
  names(df)[nm] <- 
     paste(names(df)[nm], byVal, sep="_")

  return(df[rows,])
}
```

Then can be called in merge as follows

```
# merge the two spliced data frames
merge(spliceDF(mydf, "a"), spliceDF(mydf, "b"), by="user", all=TRUE)
```

For clarity, the last line can be broken down into three separate lines

```
# Splice the df into two separate dfs
df_a <- spliceDF(mydf, byVal="a", byCol="attr")
df_b <- spliceDF(mydf, byVal="b", byCol="attr")

# mrege the two into one
merge(df_a, df_b, by="user", all=TRUE)
```

---

*code for your example above*

```
# build the data frame from your example
mydf <- data.frame(user=c(100,100,101), 
                   attr=c("a","b","a"), 
                   val =c(10, 20, 11), 
                   date=c(2012-11-09,2012-11-08,2012-11-09)
                  )
```

---

### UPDATE:

looking at the `?merge()`, it has a suffixes argument.
Trying suffixes=c("_a", "_b") works well.

```
    merge(df[df$attr=="a", ], df[df$attr=="b", ],
           by="user", suffixes=c("_a", "_b"), all=TRUE)

# OUTPUT
  user attr_a val_a date_a attr_b val_b date_b
1  100      a    10   1992      b    20   1993
2  101      a    11   1992   <NA>    NA     NA
```

Comment: Thanks!
This is precisely what I was looking for. January's solution is similar too.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
merge( df[ df$attr == "a", ], df[ df$attr == "b", ], by= "user" )
```